# data.find('#myDiv') is not a function in $.post request

Tags: jquery, ajax

why can't i select the div i need using $.post?

trying at callback function:

```
$.post("file.php", { param_s: $('#input').val()},
               function(data) {
                 $('#'+donde).html(data.find('#router').html);

});
```

And firebug jumps:

> data.find is not a function

normally i would `$('#where').load('file.php?param=foo #myDiv')` but this file responds by `$_POST`..

how can i manipulate the data response so i can filter the desired selector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `find` is a jQuery method and `data` is not a jQuery object, `find` is undefined.

Simply wrap `data` in a jQuery object:

```
$.post("file.php", { param_s: $('#input').val() }, function(data) {
     $('#'+donde).html( $(data).find('#router').html() );
});
```